# How is the default __repr__ implemented for python type objects?

Tags: python

Say I create a new class as part of a metaclass:

```py
import six

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, name, bases, attrs):
        nt = type.__new__(mcl, name, bases, attrs)

        class NestedClass(object):
            pass
        print(NestedClass)

        return nt

class Foo(six.with_metaclass(Meta), object):
    pass
```

In Python 2, I get:
`<class '__main__.NestedClass'>`
whereas in Python 3, I get:
`<class '__main__.Meta.__new__.<locals>.NestedClass'>`

I know that I can control the behavior of `__repr__()` by implementing my own version on `Meta`, for example:

```py
class Meta(type):
    # ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<class '{}'>.format(self.__name__)"
```

However, I am mostly curious where the default Python 3 version is getting "`__main__.Meta.__new__.<locals>.`" from at call time. Inspecting the class object, I am not seeing any state that stores it. Is it getting baked straight into the `__repr__()` function itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the combination of `__module__` and `__qualname__` (new in python3 via [PEP 3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/))

Adjusting your example slightly:

```
import six

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, name, bases, attrs):
        nt = type.__new__(mcl, name, bases, attrs)

        class NestedClass(object):
            pass
        print(NestedClass)
        # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        print(NestedClass.__module__)
        print(NestedClass.__qualname__)
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        return nt

class Foo(six.with_metaclass(Meta), object):
    pass
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ python3 t.py 
<class '__main__.Meta.__new__.<locals>.NestedClass'>
__main__
Meta.__new__.<locals>.NestedClass
```

Note that python 2.x does not have `__qualname__` so you'll need to adjust with something like `getattr(cls, '__qualname__', '__name__')` to be compatible

Comment: Thank you. I am able to get `NestedClass.__qualname__`, but I do not see where it lives. It isn't in `__dict__` or `dir(NestedClass)`. Where is `__qualname__` stored?

Comment: It's part of the type itself (you can think of it similar to __slots__). Cpython implements it as a getter "property" : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/typeobject.c#L871 (usually deferring to the ht_qualname struct field)