# Can a decorator name classes it creates?

Tags: python

I have a decorator which wraps functions and produces classes (for a better reason than in the following example). It all works, except that I'd like to be able to set the name of the class given by `type()`.

For example,

```
>>> class Animal:
...     pass
... 
>>> def linnean_name(genus, species):
...     def _linnean_name(fn):
...         class _Animal(Animal):
...             binomial_name = (genus, species)
...             def converse(self):
...                 fn()
...         _Animal.__name__ = fn.__name__.title()
...         _Animal.__module__ = fn.__module__
...         return _Animal
...     return _linnean_name
... 
>>> @linnean_name('Vombatus', 'ursinus')
... def Wombat():
...     print("Hello, I am a wombat.")
... 
>>> sheila = Wombat()
>>> sheila.binomial_name
('Vombatus', 'ursinus')
>>> sheila.converse()
Hello, I am a wombat.
```

All well and good, but

```
>>> type(sheila)
<class '__main__.linnean_name.<locals>._linnean_name.<locals>._Animal'>
```

where I was hoping to see

```
<class '__main__.Wombat'>
```

This was the reason for

```
...         _Animal.__name__ = fn.__name__.title()
...         _Animal.__module__ = fn.__module__
```

which appear not to do anything particularly useful. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to override \`\_\_name\_\_\` derived from object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769020/is-it-possible-to-override-name-derived-from-object)

Comment: @user2722968 that doesn't answer the question; the code already overrides `__name__`. The problem is that `__name__` isn't what gets used in the `repr` of the class in modern versions of Python; `__qualname__` is. The other question is from 2012, when it would have worked (the "qualification" of the name would have been discovered on the fly by `repr`).

Comment: The closest existing question I can find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561074 , but I think this one is better quality although it sets a different context for the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, retracted, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: You will need to change [qualname](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58108488/13629335) as well, which is not advisable at all. Qualified names are not meant to look pretty, rather it should tell you exactly where the object to be found. [Also see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python functools.wraps equivalent for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394511/python-functools-wraps-equivalent-for-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `__new__`. It allows you to specify a new class name and share a common base class for pre-defined behavior. You could also make MixIn classes by define more bases/base classes etc.

```
class Animal:

    def talk(self):
        print(f"Hello, I am {self}")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.family} {self. spec}'

    def __new__(cls, family, spec,  *args, **kwargs):
        cls_name = family.title() + spec.title()
        bases = (cls,)
        typ = type(cls_name, bases, {})
        obj = object.__new__(typ)
        #from here it's like __init__
        #except you return the object instead of None
        #obj is equal to self in the __init__ here

        obj.family = family
        obj.spec = spec
        return obj
    pass


sheila = Animal('Vombatus', 'ursinus')
sheila.talk()
```

As mentioned in the comments, you actually don't have to use a class and `__new__` you can just have a *factory* that uses `type`. However, in my opinion `__new__` is more readable.

```
class Animal:

    def talk(self):
        print(f"Hello, I am {self}")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.family} {self. spec}'
    pass

def factory(family, spec, *args, **kwargs):
    cls_name = family.title() + spec.title()
    bases = (Animal,)
    typ = type(cls_name, bases, {})
    obj = typ(*args, **kwargs)
    obj.family = family
    obj.spec = spec
    return obj


sheila = factory('Vombatus', 'ursinus')
print(type(sheila))
sheila.talk()
```

Comment: Why put this in `__new__` and a class to begin with? Using `type` is fine, but why not just use a function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess a factory function is just fine, but it would look more obscure than this in my opinion.

Comment: Well, the key thing here isn't `__new__`, it's that you are using `type`, so I would at least point that out

Comment: You are right, that the answer was misleading in the sense that one **have** to use `__new__` and I've updated to this point.